# What is the compatible version of @angular/core for typescript 2.5?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using typescript 2.5.3 and can't upgrade it due to other dependencies. Is there a compatible version of @angular/core for ts 2.5? Installing the latest @angular/core gives me error as below:

```
angular-js/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12341,86): error TS1110: Type expected.
angular-js/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12341,92): error TS1005: '=' expected.
angular-js/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12341,94): error TS1005: ')' expected.
angular-js/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12341,95): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
angular-js/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12341,96): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

package.json:

```
 "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
 "typescript": "2.5.3"
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "es5",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declarationDir": angular-js/types",
    "outDir": "dist-esm",
    "rootDir": "angular-js/src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: No idea why my question is downvoted... but I tried to use different versions (7.0 and 6.0) of @angular/core but gives more errors, and tried to config tsconfig.json file with what list here on angular website: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration but it didn't work neither. I'm new to Angular and not sure how to fix dependency problems... It would be really appreciate if you have any idea what I'm missing here... thanks

Comment: Try upgrading typescript instead. They should all be mostly backwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks Evert, the problem is I'm working on a small part of the project and can't update typescript that will break other parts... Thanks anyway!

Comment: are you sure it will break other parts? If so, it might still be less work to do that, instead of trying to get an old library work with another old library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searched two days found

`"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "^5.0.0"`

works for ts 2.5, yay~